# Can I install nodejs v.8.12 on CentOS 6x?

Tags: node.js, centos6

Now I have faced to install nodejs v.8.12 on centOS 6.9
When I try to install v8x, I can get only v6.12

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon repo...


## Inspecting system...

+ rpm -q --whatprovides redhat-release || rpm -q --whatprovides centos-release || rpm -q --whatprovides cloudlinux-release || rpm -q --whatprovides sl-release
+ uname -m

## Confirming "el6-x86_64" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/6/x86_64/nodesource-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm'

## Downloading release setup RPM...

+ mktemp
+ curl -sL -o '/tmp/tmp.eY4nFtJJtc' 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/6/x86_64/nodesource-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm'

## Installing release setup RPM...

+ rpm -i --nosignature --force '/tmp/tmp.eY4nFtJJtc'

## Cleaning up...

+ rm -f '/tmp/tmp.eY4nFtJJtc'

## Checking for existing installations...

+ rpm -qa 'node|npm' | grep -v nodesource

## Run `sudo yum install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon and npm.
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo yum install gcc-c++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
     sudo yum install yarn
```

I've just followed their instruction to get nodejs v8.x,

### Run `sudo yum install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon and npm.

But still get only 6.14.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `nvm` then download Nodejs 8x and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to update to desired version

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 8.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Install nvm and then use your desired node version.
To install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc

nvm install v0.8.12
```

[Check the documentation.](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)